# Analysis of k-means results in R

Tags: r, k-means

I have performed k-means clustering in R, and I am having trouble analyzing the results. I am simply trying to create a data frame containing the imported data frame together with the cluster ID and cluster center for each observation so I can further explore the accuracy of the results, such as the percentage of observations in between 1/2 standard deviations and so on.

This is the code I have used:

```
iris = read.csv("C:\\Users\\newuser\\Desktop\\Data Anlysis\\Data Sets\\iris.csv")
results = kmeans(iris, 3)
```

Using the following vectors:

```
results$cluster

results$centers
```

And the following data frame:

```
iris
```

containing the observations, which has the columns: "X1", "X2", "X3"

I would like to create a data frame containing the following columns in each row: "X1", "X2", "X3", "ClusterID", "X1_Center", "X2_Center" and "X3_Center"

Comment: Adding `clusterID` to `iris` makes sense `iris <- cbind(iris,ClusterID=results$cluster)`, but not sure adding `centers` to `iris` makes any sense.

Answer (score 2):

Creating the data frame is straight forward, although I think that the "X1_Center" column which is actually 4 columns because you have 4 different features is the best answer to your actual needs, I don't think it is.

however this is the code to produce it

```
results = kmeans(iris[,c("Sepal.Length","Sepal.Width","Petal.Length","Petal.Width")], 3)
library(data.table)
data <- iris
setDT(data)

# creating cluster_ID
data[,cluster_ID:=results$cluster]

# creating the X1, X@, X3 columns
data[,':='(X1=0,X2=0,X3=0)]
data[cluster_ID==1,X1:=1]
data[cluster_ID==2,X2:=1]
data[cluster_ID==3,X3:=1]

# add the duplicated center cordinates
data <- cbind(data,rep(1,nrow(data)) %*% t.default(results$centers[1,]))
data <- cbind(data,rep(1,nrow(data)) %*% t.default(results$centers[2,]))
data <- cbind(data,rep(1,nrow(data)) %*% t.default(results$centers[3,]))

# setnames for the addded columns
setnames(data,c(names(data)[1:9],
            paste0("X1_center_",names(data)[1:4]),
            paste0("X2_center_",names(data)[1:4]),
            paste0("X3_center_",names(data)[1:4])))
```